# Add different type of column using Vue and element ui

Tags: jquery, vue.js, element-ui

I am looking for an example or a way to generate table having each row have different kind of columns.

I read the documentation of [Element UI table](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) but, could not found that kind of customization.

Please refer the image here. I want to achieve this kind of functionality, if anybody have implement in past or can give me some suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `<template slot-scope="scope">`

Check this example for an element-ui table : https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#custom-column-template

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      label="Operations">
      <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-button v-if="scope.row.date === '2016'">
          Edit
        </el-button>
        <el-select v-if="scope.row.date === '2017'">
          <el-option
            v-for="item in 3"
            :key="item"
            :label="item"
            :value="item">
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
```

And if you want I did a code pen : https://codepen.io/Andugal/pen/JjjbBvE